# Monotonicity of the sequence $\frac{(n/e)^n}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

When I draw the discrete function $f:\mathbb{N}_1\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ that is defined as follows
$$
f(n) := \frac{(n/e)^n}{n!}
$$
using Wolfram Alpha, the graph is descendant. Is it true that $f$ is non-increasing? Strictly decreasing? If so, how can this be proved? I tried investigating the behavior of the sequence $f(n+1)/f(n)$, however it converges to $1$, so this was no help.

Comment: Yes, and this follows directly from the inequality $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\lt e$ for every positive $n$.

Comment: Disregard what $f(n+1)/f(n)$ converges to. You just need to prove $f(n+1)/f(n)<1$ for all $n$ - and Did's comment makes that fairly easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)} = \frac{((n+1)/e)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{(n/e)^n}$$

Use that $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n < e$.

Comment: I think numberator of the middle fraction needs exponent of $n+1$, not $n$.

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks!